# How to copy file to Ubuntu from Windows via PowerShell script

Tags: windows, powershell, ubuntu

Source is Windows and destination is Ubuntu (installed on VMware player).

I ran below script in Windows:

```
$targetComputerName = "192.168.22.130"
$Username = 'zahid'
$Password = 'Z@hid1212'
$Pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force 
$SecureString= $pass
$MySecureCreds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$SecureString

$Session = New-PSSession $targetComputerName -Credential $MySecureCreds
$DestinationPath = "/home/zahid/Downloads"
$Source = 'D:\zahid.txt'

Copy-Item -Path $Source -ToSession $Session -Destination $DestinationPath
$Session | Remove-PSSession
```

and got error:

```
New-PSSession : [192.168.22.130] Connecting to remote server 192.168.22.130 failed with the following error message : The client cannot connect to the destination 
specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management 
service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the destination to analyze and 
configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig". For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Untitled1.ps1:8 char:12
+ $Session = New-PSSession $targetComputerName -Credential $MySecureCre ...
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConnect,PSSessionOpenFailed
Copy-Item : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ToSession'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command 
again.
At C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Untitled1.ps1:12 char:36
+ Copy-Item -Path $Source -ToSession $Session -Destination $Destination ...
+                                    ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

Do I need to setup winrm service on destination (here is Ubuntu) also? How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

I used to use [WinScp](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell) with PowerShell, or [Posh-SSH](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Posh-SSH/2.1).
These two ways allow you exploit conventional SSH on Linux.

Begining with PowerShell 6 you can use [PowerShell remoting over SSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-7.1), this link show you the setup on Windows and Ubuntu.